# How do i change original Ellipse color to green after saving

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 5 Ellipse Circle with a color red, the user will select one at a time. now i want to change the selected ellipse to green after i have saved. how do i do that?

```
private void Right1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    nfingerIndex = 1;
}

private void Right2_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    nfingerIndex = 2;
}

private void Right3_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    nfingerIndex = 3;
}

private void Right4_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    nfingerIndex = 4;
}

private void Right5_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    nfingerIndex = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ellipses dont have Background properties. They have Fill properties and you can change them with using this code.

```
 private void Right1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        nfingerIndex = 1;
        ((Ellipse)sender).Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    }
```

this code will change the Fill property of the Ellipse which is clicked.

**And if i'm not wrong, you have added a Click event to Ellipses. Ellipses dont have Click property. You can try MouseLeftButtonUp event.**

Comment: Don't i have to specify the finger index or will it override all the Ellipse?

Comment: I know how to change the color. i want to change the color after an event performed

Comment: Do you mean, you want to change color AFTER Right1_Click performed ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to my problem. i managed to do it like this

```
 private void invokeControlColour(int FingerIndex)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (FingerIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        Right1.Fill = Brushes.Green;
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        Right2.Fill = Brushes.Green;
                        break;
                    } 
                case 3:
                    {
                        Right3.Fill = Brushes.Green;
                        break;
                    } 
                case 4:
                    {
                        Right4.Fill = Brushes.Green;
                        break;
                    } 
                case 5:
                    {
                        Right5.Fill = Brushes.Green;
                        break;
                    }
```

and the invoke it like this

```
               Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => invokeControlColour(nfingerIndex)));
```